# iPhone 4 - photos are chopped off on the side

Tags: ios, iphone, hdr

I have been using my iPhone 4 to take photos on my holiday, and have been noticing that approximately 10% of the photos I have taken are chopped a bit shorter. I have only noticed it happening on landscape shots, and I have HDR enabled without the option to keep the original. Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is an issue at all. In the Photos app, all pictures are slightly zoomed in on by default to fill the entire screen. If you zoom out on each picture using your fingers, you will notice that they are all the same size.

Answer (score 0):

The photos app takes pictures that are a little bit wider than the iPhone screen. Try zooming around the pictures and see whether it's just a positioning issue in the display of them.